# Can the redirect_uri contain port number?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, oauth2

Is it possible to have the `redirect_uri` contain a specific port?

For example: `example.com:8080`

Assuming that `example.com` is my registered domain, is the `8080` allowed? I have tried to put it as part of my OAuth Domain, but get this error:

> OAuth Domain should not contain protocol or port

If I leave the port off, it does attempt to redirect properly, but my application will not be living on my main web server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got that error because you set the **`OAuth Domain`** like `example.com:8080`, not the `redirect_uri`.  That's not how you configure non-standard ports; see below.

The [redirect uri, with port, feature **now works**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308260/148310) (it didn't once upon a time).

To use, **adjust your app settings**:

1. Go to https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth and click on your desired app.
2. Click the "Edit This App" button near the bottom of the page.
3. For **`OAuth Domain`**, enter just your domain without any protocol nor port.
   EG: `example.com`
4. For **`Application Website`**, Enter a valid appropriate page on that domain, ***with port***.
   EG: `http://example.com:8080/allaboutthefooapp/`
5. Since you are using your own server, leave `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` unchecked.
6. Since you are using your own server, you normally want `Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri` checked.
7. Save the changes.

Then **in your app**, perform [the *explicit OAuth 2.0 flow*](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) with API interactions like the following **example**:

1. Send the user to: `https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=yourID&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=http://example.com:8080/yourAuthPage`
2. If the user authorizes your app, your server will see the access code in the URL parameters.
   EG: `http://example.com:8080/yourAuthPage/?code=Wu*pvlTxhN0fDpaqu17Z9w))`
3. Take the code from the previous step and POST to `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token` with the following form parameters:

   1. `client_id`: Your app's id.  EG: `1633`
   2. `client_secret`: Your app's secret code.  EG: `2VLux8e4mxSSZkYhG3doIQ((`
   3. `code`: The code from step 2. EG: `Wu*pvlTxhN0fDpaqu17Z9w))`
   4. `redirect_uri`: Must be the same as from step 1.
      EG: `http://example.com:8080/yourAuthPage`
4. The `access_token` will be in the body of the resulting page.
     EG: `access_token=ag*Vsxxxxuapy(batHWUcw))&expires=86400`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the protocol and it should work.

On my `localhost`, I am testing OAuth on a random port and it works fine, while the App setting for `redirect_uri` is just `localhost`.

Comment: @BrockAdams is `localhost` still a special case? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Alex, Not really and no.  But the good news is that OAuth now works for servers running nonstandard ports.  See my answer.