# `redirect_uri` is not under the registered domain for this application

Tags: support, oauth2, ruby

I am trying to implement Stack Exchange authorization in my RoR application.

But I get the error :

> `redirect_uri` is not under the registered domain for this application

in Gemfile use:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-stackexchange'
```

in devise.rb:

```
 config.omniauth: stackexchange, 'CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT SECRET', callback_url: 'stackexchange.com'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about that Ruby/Gem, but your app registration is not correct.

**You need to configure your app for explicit OAuth2, per [this other answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7852/7653), *except* enter `localhost` instead of `example.com`.**

<sup>(The localhost is based on the original version of the question.  If you have a registered domain, use that.)</sup>

Then, in your ruby code:

```
config.omniauth: stackexchange, 'CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT SECRET', callback_url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

(Assuming the rest of that `devise.rb` code was correct.  But see [the *OmniAuth StackExchange* doc/GitHub](https://github.com/nashby/omniauth-stackexchange) about that.)