# Localhost test Stack App authentication: error 'redirect_uri' does not match

Tags: support, authentication, oauth2, stackapps, ruby

I tried the [answer at "Can the redirect_uri contain port number"?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4596/can-the-redirect-uri-contain-port-number/7852#7852)

But I am getting the following error:

> Provided `redirect_uri` does not match the `redirect_uri` this code was created with

My access log looks like:

```
::1 - - [14/Mar/2019:22:49:31 CST] "GET /auth/stackexchange/callback?code=umZowLeAHg*z6Gs*(yIBUg))&state=7a24d06c83edd66415483ce0b32d1bd8714b730215a30e9c HTTP/1.1" 302 9http://localhost:3000/ -> /auth/stackexchange/callback?code=umZowLeAHg*z6Gs(yIBUg))&state=7a24d06c83edd66415483ce0b32d1bd8714b730215a30e9c

Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fabbc%2Fedit&strategy=stackexchange" for ::1 at 2019-03-14 22:49:50 +0800

::1 - - [14/Mar/2019:22:49:50 CST] "GET /auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fabbc%2Fedit&strategy=stackexchange HTTP/1.1" 301 88http://localhost:3000/ -> /auth/failuremessage=invalid_credentials&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fabbc%2Fedit&strategy=stackexchange
```

I used Rails and my code is like this:

```
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.6'
gem 'omniauth-stackexchange', '~> 0.2.1'

# initializers/omniauth.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :stackexchange, Rails.application.secrets.stack_client_id, Rails.application.secrets.stack_client_secret, public_key: Rails.application.secrets.stack_key, site: 'stackoverflow',callback_url:'http://localhost:3000/'
end
```

My Stack Apps application settings are like this:

- **OAuth Domain:** localhost
- **Application Website:** http://localhost:3000/
- **Stack Apps Post:** Not set
- **Client Side Flow**: Disabled
- **Desktop OAuth Redirect Uri**: Disabled

These are screenshots of the settings on the app's page:

[image]

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not a Ruby expert, but that doesn't look like how others use `omniauth-stackexchange`.  See [this other Q&A](https://stackapps.com/questions/8238/redirect-uri-is-not-under-the-registered-domain-for-this-application) for example.

Answer (score 1):

I get the reason:

Do not use `gem 'omniauth-stackexchange', '~> 0.2.1'` ,but instead of `gem 'omniauth-stackexchange', git: 'https://github.com/nashby/omniauth-stackexchange.git'`

The reason see this:[add call back url](https://github.com/nashby/omniauth-stackexchange/issues/7)