# How to register a Stack App with explicit OAuth 2.0 flow to a third party site?

Tags: support, oauth2, apps

I am about to integrate a Stack Overflow app to a third party website / integration service (Zoho).

The third party website's documentation mentioned that the redirect URL is `https://deluge.zoho.com/delugeauth/callback`.
I gave this URL as the OAuth Domain during stack app registration.

And I did not not enable `Client Side OAuth Flow` and I enabled `Desktop OAuth Redirect Uri`.

After I had given all the credentials (Client id,Secret,Authorize url,access token url), I'm getting this message:

> redirect_uri is not under the registered domain for this application

Please do help me connect the Stack Exchange API to the third party site.

Comment: (1) Provide a link to that do that documentation. (2) **How** did you give " all the credentials (Client id,Secret,Authorize url,access token url)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a URI is not a domain, but this seems to be a common mistake when setting up OAuth2.

Also reference:

- [`redirect_uri` is not under the registered domain for this application](https://stackapps.com/questions/8238/redirect-uri-is-not-under-the-registered-domain-for-this-application)
- [What exactly is a valid OAuth domain name for registering your app?](https://stackapps.com/questions/7857/what-exactly-is-a-valid-oauth-domain-name-for-registering-your-app)
- [Can the redirect_uri contain port number?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4596/can-the-redirect-uri-contain-port-number)  This answer **has detailed instructions** on how to set-up and use explicit OAuth with the Stack Exchange API.

So, apparently, on your Stack Apps configuration page you would set `OAuth Domain` to `zoho.com` (not deluge.zoho.com, and not to a URL).

Also: **Disable** `Desktop OAuth Redirect Uri` in this case.

Comment: I changed oauth domain to zoho.com and disabled ''Desktop OAuth Redirect Uri". Now after i connect, i'm getting "Processing" message still for infinite time :(

Comment: That sounds like a new problem and possibly a Zoho issue.  You can open a new question for that, but only if you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).