# Requesting Assistance for OAuth Implementation in the Stack Overflow API

Tags: support, stackapps, stackoverflow, stack-overflow-for-teams, node.js

I'm attempting to set up OAuth in the Stack Overflow API. I've created a Stack App and obtained the Client ID and Client Secret. However, I'm encountering difficulties in the process and require guidance on the parameters necessary for code generation in the Stack Overflow API.

Currently, I'm providing the following parameters:

```
client_id: *****
scope: no_expiry
client_secret: ***********
redirect_uri: https://*********.com
response_type: code
```

I'm using the API endpoint https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/oauth/code? for code generation, but it doesn't seem to be generating the code as expected.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding the correct parameters and API endpoints required for code generation and obtaining an access token for OAuth implementation.

Comment: Where did you find that `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/oauth/code` is a valid endpoint? :Looking at the public API [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) I only see `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth`, `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog` and  `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json` and if you're using the Stack Overflow for Teams endpoint I only see an implict flow to `https://stackoverflowteams.com/oauth/dialog`. What flow did you configure in your Registered Stack App?

Comment: Here is an answer with extra pointers: https://stackapps.com/a/8399/18722 Maybe that gives some insight in where your solution is off.